# Guardar texto de elemento Selenium en un array mediante un ciclo for

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy buscando que por cada iteración del bucle `for` se guarde el texto del elemento en un array.
Procedo a mostrar código:

```
# Select employees
    def select_employees(self):
        def cuenta():
            cuenta.numero += 2
            return cuenta.numero

        cuenta.numero = 0
        emp_generados = []

        for i in range(8):

            self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                     '//*[@id="tableBodyEmpleados"]/tr[' + str(cuenta()) + ']/td/div/label').click()
            print(cuenta())
```

Como pueden ver tengo un método que lo que hace es seleccionar un `label` que en la página web representa un empleado. Aclaración importante: por cada iteración Selenium va cambiando el xpath seleccionando diferentes `tr[cuenta()]`: necesitaría guardar el texto de cada uno de ellos sin pisar ningún dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que hagas clic obtendrás un texto. Puedes añadirlo al array con `append`.

```
    emp_generados = []

    for i in range(8):

         driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="lo que sea   ...').click()
         texto=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="lo que sea ...').text
         emp_generados.append(texto)

    print(emp_generados)
```

Comment: Hola gracias, anteriormente lo pude resolver exactamente de la misma forma que tu respuesta. Gracias por tu aporte.